# WebElement click() not working in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, selenium-chromedriver, junit4

I was learning automated selenium testing in https://www.yatra.com/etw-desktop/. While trying to click an image  button named 'Asia'(image is attached) ,I am getting a Time out exception. Please help me in figuring out what's going wrong .

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
driver.get("https://www.yatra.com/etw-desktop/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Thread.sleep(5000);
        
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"scrollable1\"]/div[1]/div/a[2]/div[4]"))).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
        
Assert.assertEquals("https://www.yatra.com/etw-desktop/city-list",driver.getCurrentUrl());
```

[image showing the web element to be clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAKpF.png)

Comment: Why are you using `Thread.sleep()`? It's not a good practice to do so.
You're waiting for a `div` to be clickable, try the surrounding link instead: `//*[@id="scrollable1"]/div[1]/div/a[2]`

Comment: The whole thing is under shadow root elements you need to use /deep/ to get those elements.

Comment: Can you describe more about the /deep/ concept. I feel that the web element is hidden or something since I tried implicit and explicit waits and also tried a JavaScript click without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably because of using `Thread.sleep()`, which is the worst case of explicit wait. Instead use the wait method provided by selenium itself.

Comment: I was not using Thread.sleep() in the beginning and was getting the same error. So I added sleep to get enough time for the page to load and still the same error is present. I think its not beacause of sleep but the web element is hiddden or something.

Comment: the element is under a #shadow-root(open) which I am seeing for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[How to Find Web Elements in Shadow DOMs using Selenium](https://medium.com/@alan.canlin/how-to-find-web-elements-in-shadow-doms-using-selenium-webdriver-and-c-36978f7de9ba)